# Consulta SQL Moodle

Tags: sql, moodle

Estou com um problema, e não tenho muito conhecimento em SQL para montar uma Query dessa, que retorne exatamente isso, estou trabalhando com o Moodle, e preciso retornar com uma consulta, como seguintes informações.

Nome do Aluno | Curso | Avaliação 1 | Avaliação 2 | Avaliação n | Nota final

As tabelas são **mdl_course** (Armazena todos os cursos), **mdl_role_assignments** (Lista os alunos inscritos em cursos), **mdl_grade_items** (Extrai a lista das avaliações), **mdl_grade_grades** (Extrair a lista de nota de todas as avaliações). basicamente são essas, eu achei um link que ajudaria

[Link](https://moodlesql.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/relatorio-completo-de-nota-de-um-curso.html?showComment=1490279643106#c5971733205604944253)

Porem, é para um curso especifico, eu quero para todos os cursos que possuir em minha tabela

Lembrando que cada um está em uma tabela diferente, alguem que trabalha com o Moodle, saberia me dizer?

Comment: Cadê o esquema? Você não tem isso na documentação do Moodle?

Comment: Era bom ser mais completo na pergunta, informar as chaves de cada tabela, o nome das tabelas que cada campo se encontra para melhor entendimento.

Comment: As tabelas são mdl_course (Armazena todos os cursos), mdl_role_assignments (Lista os alunos inscritos em cursos), mdl_grade_items (Extrai a lista das avaliações), mdl_grade_grades (Extrair a  lista de nota de todas as avaliações).

basicamente são essas, eu achei um link que ajudaria 
https://moodlesql.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/relatorio-completo-de-nota-de-um-curso.html?showComment=1490279643106#c5971733205604944253

Porem, é para um curso especifico, eu quero para todos os cursos que possuir em minha tabela

Comment: Isso não deve estar nos comentários, mas sim na pergunta. Se puder editar e de detalhar melhor.

Comment: Eu editei, Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode utilizar JOIN para pegar as tabelas referentes que precisa, seria legal dar uma olhada apenas para aprender.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho conhecimento em **Moodle**, mas montei algo em cima do que você passou e os exemplos em **Moodle**, tens que ver as chaves das tabelas para montar o SQL.

```
SELECT
   rs.nome_aluno,
   c.curso,
   gi.avaliacao,
   ggrades.nota_final
FROM mdl_role_assignmets rs
INNER JOIN mdl_course c on c.id da tabela = rs.id da tabela dos alunos
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi on gi.id da tabela = c.id da tabela cursos
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades ggrades on ggrades.id da tabela = gi.id da tabela avaliacoes
```

Comment: @Rafael Augusto, se a resposta te ajudou, poderia marca-la, assim ajudaria os outros usuários. Abraços!